# Override dojo module without modify the compact and minified file

Tags: javascript, dojo, touch

What I need is to apply a fix from dojo 1.10 into dojo 1.9. This fix is related to the iOS 8 crashing touch events on dojo.

Due to the specifications of the project, I cannot upgrade dojo or modify the dojo original files, so I need to patch it someway.

The fix

https://github.com/dojo/dojo/pull/104

doesn't affect to a method inside the 'on' module, it affect to the module instanciation instead, so I cannot extend the module.

Does anybody know a way to patch this? I tried to do it but it doesn't work (I checked by my own that the fix works correctly replacing that in the dojo source code, but I cannot do that for the real product as I mentioned before). I think the issue is related to the variables scope, specifically with 'fixTouchListener', as it is maybe not extended into the methods used by the class and I cannot access to it as is not a property of the module result.

Comment: If you can't modify dojo source, you can't apply any fix. Is there any particular reason why you "can't" modify the dojo source? Problems with build, for example?

Comment: Well, it's a bit messy to describe the reasons why I cannot modify it (related with frameworks and IDEs), but believe me I wish it'd be that easy.

What I did so far was try to apply the patch after dojo is loaded (overriding and extending some of the properties of the on module in a separate file), but it just didn't work and it's not elegant (too many variables to replace the closures).

Comment: The other tried was unload the module on require before the app is init and load the new one, but I cannot 'unlock' the require.undef method (it should be unlocked with the flag dojo-undef-api in the hasCache property of the dojoConfig, but the method is not available). Is there any other way to unload and load an AMD module in dojo?